Negative Binomial GLM - Overflow in the link function
I am trying to create a GLM to model some count data.
I am using the pymc package in python.
The set up is what I believe to be the usual set up:
$$Y \sim NB(\mu,k) $$
$$E(Y\vert\mathbf{X}) = \mu $$
$$\mu = \exp{(\eta)}$$
$$\eta = \beta_0+\sum_{i=1}^j\beta_iX_i$$
The issue I am facing is that the value for $\mu$ is overflowing because of the large values of the $\eta$. I appreciate that this is caused by the $\exp{}$ function.
Scaling the $\mathbf{X}$ (by standardisation or normalisation) does not fix the issue, and I am (possibly wrongly) reluctant to scale the $Y$ values as I am under the impression they need to stay as discrete counts.
The maximum $Y$ value is around 12,000. The minimum is 170.
Should I really be seeing overflow when I wouldn't expect (again, maybe wrongly) that the largest $\mu$ should be much less than 12,000, which shouldn't be causing any overflows?
I am able to model successfully if I scale $\eta$ by its maximum value before passing it into the $\exp{}$ function, but I'm not sure that this is valid. The values I get for $\beta_i$ in this instance seem to all bunch together which I would not expect. I have considered shifting $\eta$ by its maximum value as well, but the modelling takes a long time.
The next thing I was thinking of trying was to scale the $\mathbf{X}$ and $Y$ data and use a gamma distribution instead.
Would love any thoughts!
EDIT
Apologies I had my max and min values incorrect above.
Also, I am modelling a hierarchical model, so the maximum value and the minimum value are across two cross sections. In one cross section the min-max is 45-1138, and in the other cross section the min-max is 5841-12,177.

If the range of your data is on the order of $(170, 12,000)$, using a discrete distribution to model it is pretty pointless, count data or not.  Try a Gamma distribution with a log link... how sure are you that a log link is even appropriate here?  Alternatively, you could just take the log of your data and model that using a linear regression; it's a different model, but it may be just as good from the perspective of your end objective.

Thanks @jbowman - I have edited my question above if that makes any difference to your comment. I am not completely sure that a log-link is totally appropriate here, particularly because the $\eta$ value will always be positive anyway. Using an identity link did not model very well though, so I guess I was just following the most common examples. Should I try the gamma with scaled $Y$?

Yes, I'd try the Gamma dist'n, but there is no point in scaling the $Y$ values with a Gamma dist'n, since it has a scale parameter anyway.  You might also try my other suggestion.

Thank you - I will try both.
